# Python paramiko hangs when trying to run bash shell

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, python-3.x, paramiko

I need to run a regression script in bash shell on a remote server. I am able to successfully connect and execute different commands using paramiko. But when I try to execute '/bin/bash' my Python script hangs forever:

```
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("pwd;/bin/bash;echo $SHELL")
```

Without /bin/bash echo $SHELL works good and returns the following:

```
[u'/home/akar\n', u'/tools/cfr/bin/tcsh\n']
```

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

My first doubt is what is the purpose of the bash you are executing. Literally it means:

```
pwd; #print '/home/akar\n' as it results
/bin/bash; #/bin/bash will take over of console(stdin/stdout/stderr) from here
echo $SHELL #when you input exit to exit the bash from line 2, line 3 will print
```

Comment: What I need to execute is a bash script like this: stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd /project/fcd_psv/akar/neptune_psv/fw;./Do_Regr.sh -i Testlist_Regression.in -m 135.21.235.177 -g"); without doing /bin/bash it will not run

Comment: Is there any problem with stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd /project/fcd_psv/akar/neptune_psv/fw;./Do_Regr.sh -i Testlist_Regression.in -m 135.21.235.177 -g");  ?  You can call /bin/bash by passing the path of the sh file. But don't barely call /bin/bash;